# Query - Get last inserted row id

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
$sql = "
INSERT INTO table
( a, b, c )
VALUES
( 1, 2, 3 )";

$result_set = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
```

How do I now echo the last inserted row id?

Thanks guys..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve the ID of an inserted record: Php & MS SQL SERVER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850375/retrieve-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-php-ms-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

In case you insert to a SqlServer, like the Tag in your question says.

The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gives you the last inserted Id.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table
        ( a, b, c )
        VALUES
        ( 1, 2, 3 )

        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as newId ";
```

Comment: I think  SCOPE_IDENTITY() will work if he has an IDENTITY column in the table

Comment: Yes i think so too. The insert statement looks like there is a identity column.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbres = sqlsrv_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$dbrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($dbres);
$lastInsertId = $dbrow[0];
```

You can do that this way, but maybe another insert can occur before you get your insert id and mess everything up, so it's better this way:

```
INSERT into table(a, b, c) OUTPUT Inserted.a, Inserted.b, Inserted.c VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

or this way:

```
INSERT into table(a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as lastId
```