# How to get the last inserted id for sqlsrv driver for PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am using [sqlsrv driver for PHP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098) for inserting into the SQL SERVER 2012 database. The values are getting inserted property. But I cannot get the last inserted id. I am doing the following:

```
$sql = "insert into test_table(property_name, property_value) 
        values ('testprop', 'testval');";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );

sqlsrv_next_result($stmt); 
sqlsrv_fetch($stmt); 
$id =  sqlsrv_get_field($stmt, 0);
```

The above code is in line with the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850375/retrieve-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-php-ms-sql-server). However it is not working.
$id is always coming as 'false'.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have seen the other question. The accepted answer there doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: you cannot use `sqlsrv_get_field` for insert query. From documentation  *Gets field data from the currently **selected** row*.  sqlsrv_next_result, sqlsrv_fetch also works with select.

Comment: @devnull You should add  `; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in the end of your `$sql` string to get the last inserted ID with this code.