# Return ID of inserted record from MS SQL Server Query in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to return the id result from this query using "OUTPUT INSERTED.ID". In my SQL Server Management Studio I get the id of the newly inserted row. I need to return that result.

I am trying this, I know the connection is working and everything because it is making the insert into the table. But $value still returns 0.

```
public function Insert($NewSql) {
$value = '0';
$params = array(array($value,SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT));
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn, $NewSql, $params);
return $value;

}
```

The parameter NewSql = "Insert Into Test (Col1) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES ('SomeValues')";

For some reason $value is still returning 0.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850375/retrieve-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-php-ms-sql-server for a full already accepted answer

Comment: There is no actual answer. There is some bad copy and paste code that does not work...

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
 public function Insert($IncomingSql) {
    //Append the Select for Scope_Identity to IncomingSql
    $sql = $IncomingSql.'; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();';
    $Result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql); 
    sqlsrv_next_result($Result); 
    sqlsrv_fetch($Result);

    return sqlsrv_get_field($Result, 0); 

}
```

Then call it like

```
$ID = Insert("Insert Into Table (SomeColumn) Values ('SomeValue)") and $ID will have the last inserted ID.
```