# How to get last inserted id from sqlsrv_execute() with prepared statement for multiple inserts?

Tags: php, sql-server, prepared-statement

I'm pretty new at **PHP**, but I'm trying to address it. Let's say I have an insert prepared statement (`sqlsrv_prepare()`), that I would re-use multiple times by just replacing variable values, then re-executing it.

The `foo` table uses `IDENTITY(1,1)`.

My statement is:

```
insert into foo (bar, baz) 
values (?, ?); 

Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as LAST_ID;
```

My parameter array is composed by `array( &$bar, &$baz)`. This way, For a thousand inserts, I could just replace `$bar` and `$baz` values and re-run the statement.

But here is the question: Since `sqlsrv_execute()` returns a bool value, how could I retrieve the last "statement-inserted" Id to push it onto an array?

I know that I could just use `sqlsrv_query()` to do that... I don't know, but I think it would be slower (since `sqlsrv_query()` [prepares and executes a query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-query.php), so I think, internally it would run a "prepare function" every time it runs) than executing the same statement multiple times by just replacing parameter values.

I know how to get last inserted id, which row was inserted using `sqlsrv_query()` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850375/retrieve-the-id-of-an-inserted-record-php-ms-sql-server), and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickhodge/archive/2008/09/23/sql-server-driver-for-php-last-inserted-row-id.aspx).

How could I accomplish that for `sqlsrv_execute()`? Am I doing it wrong way?

Thank you in advance!